# Converting a ruby method from method() to ().method

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to programming so I'm sorry if I'm asking a really simple question. I've also already done my research and I still can't get what I want so I'm asking here.

So I'm writing a simple camelcase method - All words must have their first letter capitalized without spaces. Right now in order to call this function I have to type camelcase("hello there") which would return "Hello There" in interactive ruby. I am wondering how to convert this method into a different type of method(I think it's called a class method?) which would allow me to do this instead: "hello there".camelcase #=> "Hello There"

I've also seen that the syntax would be like so:

```
class String
  def method()
  ...
  end
end
```

But I really don't know how to apply it...

```
def camelcase(string)
  newArray = []
  newNewArray = []
  array = string.split(" ")
  for i in 0...array.length
    newArray << array[i].capitalize
  end
  newNewArray = newArray.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: It _is_ a very simple question, but you also _did_ do your research, so you get answers instead of downvotes. If only there were more askers like you. :)

Comment: `"HelloThere"` (without space) would be [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). `"Hello There"` is just two capitalized words.

Comment: @Stefan true rails calls this [`titlecase`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) but then again camel case can be UpperCamelCase (Pascal case) and lowerCamelCase (traditionally camel case) :)

Comment: BTW, your implementation is very unidiomatic (temporary arrays, a `for` loop, variable names in camel case). You would usually write something like `string.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')` or `string.gsub(/[^ ]+/, &:capitalize)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just put that method into `String` class. Inside of that method, `self` will refer to the string. You don't need to (and can't) pass it as a parameter.

```
class String
  def camelcase
    newArray = []
    newNewArray = []
    array = self.split(" ")
    for i in 0...array.length
      newArray << array[i].capitalize
    end
    newNewArray = newArray.join(" ")
  end
end

'hello there'.camelcase # => "Hello There"
```

Comment: Omg I'm so dumb. Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: @zacty no question is dumb. You're helping yourself and others equally.

Answer (score 5):

In this way. I've used `your_camelcase` because I'm not sure if that method does not exist in Ruby String class. Anyway, this is an instance method and you should use `self` to refer to your string

```
class String
  def your_camelcase
    newArray = []
    newNewArray = []
    array = self.split(" ")
    for i in 0...array.length
      newArray << array[i].capitalize
    end
    newArray.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Comment: No such method on ruby. It's in rails.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-capitalize

Comment: @mudasobwa: I meant, no method named `camelcase`. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, I get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The output you want is not called Camel Case. Camelcase examples are `camelCase` or `CamelCase` (no spaces).

If you just want to capitalize each word, it is called Title Case. A naive implementation of `titlecase` is like so:

```
class String
  def titlecase
    self.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  end
end

"hello world".titlecase #=> "Hello World"
```

Note: to make it a true `camelcase` implementation, you would replace `join(" ")` with `join`.

Comment: Although actual titles usually have some exceptions like articles and prepositions.

Comment: Yes, that's why I called it a naive implementation. Interestingly, Rails' implementation doesn't exclude any words either.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, each instance you want to change is a string, so we'll need to add the method you want to the String class:

```
class String
  def camelcasify
    newArray = []
    newNewArray = []
    array = string.split(" ")
    for i in 0...array.length
      newArray << array[i].capitalize
    end
    newNewArray = newArray.join(" ")
  end
end
```

However... rails comes with a method for this built in, so you shouldn't need to do the above. Try:

```
"string".camelize
```

Comment: Rails comes with `camelcase` too.

Comment: Rails questions come with [tag:ruby-on-rails] as well :)

Comment: True but I think it's fair to put rails hints in ruby questions :)

Comment: While rails does include `camelcase` (`camelize`) what this code does and what the OP intends to do is what rails calls `titlecase` (`titleize`)